# Q: Find and Replace using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I want to find and replace using jquery, my code is like this:

```
<input id="find" style="width:100%; height:100%;" value="apple!" />

<input id="replace" style="width:100%; height:100%;" value="apples!" />

<textarea id="input" rows="4" style="width:150px; height:100px; resize:none;" wrap="off">Give me some apple</textarea>
```

> **Find:** apple!
>
> **Replace with:** apples!
>
> **Input Text:** Give me some apple!
>
> **Result:** Give me some apples!

Comment: have you tried anything from your side? On which event you want to replace text?

Comment: In which Event you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace `apple!` with `apples!` but in your text area you have only `apple` and not `apple!` (with exclamation mark). So please add `!` to your text area or remove from input fields and try below code

```
$(function(){
    $('#replaceBtn').click(function(){
         var findText = $('#find').val();
         var replaceText = $('#replace').val();
         var inputText = $('#input').val();
         inputText = inputText.replace(findText, replaceText);
         $('#input').val(inputText);
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/aaa0pe0m/10/)**

**NOTE** - Assuming that you are doing this replace on some button click. I have used `Replace` button in my demo. Also note that this replace is case sensitive.

**EDIT** - Above solution will replace only first occurance of word, to replace all occurrences you need use RegEx hence replace below line

```
inputText = inputText.replace(findText, replaceText);
```

with

```
inputText = inputText.replace(new RegExp(findText, 'g'), replaceText);
```

**[JSFiddle Demo with RegEx](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/aaa0pe0m/14/)**

Comment: this will replace only the first apple! word. but if it has more than one apple! words this is not going to work.

Comment: @Iceburg, I agree with you. Please check my edit in my answer posted. Thanks for pointing out the issue :)

Comment: you are welcome.. and below i have posted the edited version of yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("body").find("#input").replaceWith("");
```

I don't known what exactly u want to replace if u want to replace the "Give me some apple" then u can go with this code or if u want to some thing insted of "give me some apple" then u can paas the text inside the replaceWith();

Answer (score 0):

small modification to Bhushan Kawadkar's code block. and this will replace all the apple! words in single click.

```
$(function(){
 $('#replaceBtn').click(function(){
     var findText = $('#find').val();
     var replaceText = $('#replace').val();
     var textarea = $('#input');
   textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(new RegExp(findText,"g"),replaceText)); 
  });
 });
```

the "g" modifier will performs a global search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var find =$("#find").val();
var replace = $("#replace").val();
if($("#input").val().contains(find))
{
    $("#input").val($("#input").val().replace(find,replace));
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/89y6Lng5/)**